# How avoid 'no lines available in input' error when importing text files in R?

Tags: r

I have a folder with many txt. files and want to import them in one dataframe using loop expression. However, some txt. files have no data at all and thus I got an error 'no lines available in input' when importing the file.

How can I avoid this error?

```
for (i in 1:100) {
  df_new<- read.csv(paste0(PATH,i,".txt"), header=FALSE)
  df_new$id<-as.numeric(paste(i))
  df<-rbind(df,df_new)  
  print(i)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by using `tryCatch()`.

```
tryCatch(read.csv(paste0(PATH,i,".txt"), header=FALSE), error=function(e) NULL)
```